# How to get id of last inserted row from sqlx?

Tags: mysql, sql, go, sql-insert, sqlx

I'd like to get back the id of the last post inserted into MySql database using `sqlx`:

```
resultPost, err := shared.Dbmap.Exec("INSERT INTO post (user_id, description, link) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", userID, title, destPath)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    c.JSON(
        http.StatusInternalServerError,
        gin.H{"error": "internal server error"})
}

fmt.Println("resultPost is:", resultPost)
```

The problem is that the `resultPost` is printed as an object:

```
resultPost is: {0xc420242000 0xc4202403a0}
```

So I'm wondering what is the correct way to extract the id of the row just inserted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just need :

```
resultPost.LastInsertId()
```

For more information, search for LastInsertId in [this documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Result)

Comment: `LastInsertId is not supported by this driver` is what I get when using postgres

Answer (score 5):

The return value from `Exec`, [`Result`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Result) is not meant to be accessed directly--it's an object with two methods to call, one of which is `LastInsertId()`.

```
lastId, err := resultPost.LastInsertId()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("LastInsertId: ", lastId)
```

Comment: Fixed. You would do yourself a big favor to learn to read the docs directly :)

Comment: @BravoDelta: Better to just edit the question with a correction, than to leave a comment, which will eventually be deleted. But thanks for the correction. And it's now updated.