# How to get id of last inserted row from sqlx

Tags: sql, go, sqlx

I am inserting some data in table using SQLx like this

```
func (*RideRepositoryImpl) insert(entity interface{}, tx persistence.Transaction) (sql.Result, error) {
    ride := entity.(*model.Ride)

    placeHolders := repository.InsertPlaceholders(len(rideColumns))
    sql := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES(%s)", TableName, strings.Join(Columns, ","), placeHolders)
    return tx.Exec(sql, ride.ID.String(), ride.DeviceIotID, ride.VehicleID.String(), ride.UserID.String(),ride.AdditionComments)
}
```

and calling this function like this

```
func (p *RideRepositoryImpl) Save(ride *model.Ride, tx persistence.Transaction) error {
    return repository.Save(ride, p.insert, tx)
```

Now I want to get ID of  saved record instantly after saving this record . Is there any clean way to do this instantly ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need this

```
LastInsertId()
```

Check this for more information [How to get id of last inserted row from sqlx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990799/how-to-get-id-of-last-inserted-row-from-sqlx)

Comment: thanks for answer , I have gone through this question , but In my scenario I am using  `tx.Exec`  and how I will use this here ?